# NuxtJs net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, nuxtjs3, nitro

I'm having trouble displaying images on the site

**net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)**

The problem is only in displaying images

package.json

```
"nuxi": "^3.9.1",
"nuxt": "^3.7.4",
"nuxt-delay-hydration": "^1.2.3",
"vue": "^3.3.4",
```

nuxt.config.js

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,
    nitro: {
        preset: 'node-server',
        experimental: {
            writeEarlyHints: false,
        },
    },
modules: [
        "vuetify-nuxt-module",
        "@nuxt/image",
        "@nuxtjs/device",
        "nuxt-delay-hydration",
    ],
```

Nginx Configuration

```
  proxy_buffer_size      32k;
  proxy_buffers          256 48k;
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .....com;
    server_tokens off;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/1745157/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/1745157/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/server/*;
   
  location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri; 

    }
```

What is the solution to the problem? And what is the reason for it?